# Add to product list in AWS Service Catalog and Launch it

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-service-catalog

I am trying to automate AWS account creation using the AWS service catalog.

I've created a portfolio in service catalog called 'AccountFactory'. And I've added a product to the portfolio called [Account Builder](https://pasteboard.co/IgIi4mk.png).

I can see the 'AccountBuilder' under the [admin products list](https://pasteboard.co/IgPusQF.png).

But when I go to the products list on the top (not under the admin products list) that list is empty. [There is nothing there.](https://pasteboard.co/IgIgKmD.png)

How do I get my 'AccountBuilder' to appear in the upper products list where I can launch it?

Answer (score 4):

Are you logged in as the root user by chance?

I seem to remember running into an issue where I had to be logged in as an IAM user before I could launch a product using the service catalog.

Comment: Yes, I am logged in as the root user. For some reason the product catalog is empty.

Comment: Yeah - create an IAM user or assume an IAM role by switching accounts, I think this will fix it for you. I can't find any docs on this, but it definitely seems to be a thing.

Comment: OK, I tried creating an IAM user with admin privileges. I logged in as that user. And when I look at the product list, it's still empty.

Comment: This in combination with @vlence's answer below seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Products in a portfolio can only be launched and managed by users, roles or accounts that are given access to the portfolio.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/latest/adminguide/getstarted-deploy.html

Answer (score 0):

To see the product(Not under Administration) you have to go to your portfolio and assign Group,Role or User to portfolio. Once you assign, the product under portfolio will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

To launch Service Catalog product, you should give access to yourself by navigating to Portfolio --> AccountFactory portfolio--> Groups, roles and users --> Add groups, roles, users and add access to your role or user or Group